# GraphicsMagick : Command failed: identify: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/562

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick

Re-post : i have been trying to convert PDF to thumbnails(PNG format). this perfectly works on my local setup. but when i installed GraphicsMagick, ImageMagick and ghostScript on asure server(OS : UBUNTU) it's throwing error like Command failed: identify: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/562..

i have installed GraphicsMagick, ImageMagick and ghostScript locally to convert pdf pages to thumbnails and this works perfectly(not on server).

As mentioned in error , i have listed the decode delegates on local machine as well as on server . i have got many differences like bmp delegate is present local machine but not on server(UBUNTU).

I have searched a lot on web about this issue but didn't find any solution.

can anyone please help me out this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**GraphicsMagick** needs Ghostscript to read PDFs. Your system can't find Ghostscript so there are two things to do:

- find Ghostscript
- tell **GraphicsMagick** where it is

---

You should be able to find the full path to `Ghostscript` by running the following in your Terminal:

```
type gs             # or maybe "which gs", or maybe "which gs-64"
```

If that doesn't work, use whatever package manager your system has to list the names of the files included in whatever package you installed to get `Ghostscript`.

If that doesn't work, you can try:

```
find  /usr  /opt -name gs 2> /dev/null
```

---

Next, you need to find where your **GraphicsMagick** delegates are configured. This varies from system to system. I think the file is always called `delegates.mgk`:

- You could try asking your package manager to list the files included in **GraphicsMagick**
- You could run `gm convert -debug all SomeFile.pdf junk.png` and find where it looks for its coders and delegates - it will be near the start of the copious output.

If that doesn't work, you can try:

```
find /usr /opt /etc -name delegates.mgk 2> /dev/null
```

---

Finally, you need to edit the config file you just found so it includes the full path to `Ghostscript`.

I hope that helps, sorry it's a bit vague in places, but there are many different possibilities for configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the information. i'll let you know if it works or not

Answer (score 0):

Check `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` on the server. Very often the Ghostscript delegate is disabled by default due to possible security issues.